# emergent phenomena from microscopic equations of motion

Tags: emergent-properties

Is an emergent phenomenon like "superfluidity" or "quantum Hall effect" derivable from microscopic equations of motion? If No, why?

Answer (score 1):

If you Google for something like *complexity emergent properties* you'll lots of interesting background reading on the subject.

An executive summary is that physics is deterministic and therefore that all emergent properties are in principle predictable from a knowledge of the microsocpic behaviour. However in practice the complexity of the systems is so great that no such predictions can be made. This may or may not be related to chaotic evolution of the system.